# How can I make my iphone app suited to iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Currently I was designed and developed my app in iPhone . Now I wanted make my app universal(iphone and iPad).Please guide me what will be the efforts and challenges on design and development ? could you please explain the steps.

Comment: Just use autolayout for this. And autolayout are tricky things.

Comment: I think you should run your app in iPad first. You will see some (or too much) layout error. For each error, you must choose the right solution for it. Have no way to do it for all

Answer (score 0):

While developing a app and want to makeit a universal app you should have to -

1. Make sure the design compatible for both iPhone and iPad. you can check it 
   from physical devices or form the simulator.
2. Make sure all the fields are ok (not breaking down while switching the 
   devices).
3. Make sure all the scrolling are working for both iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score -1):

The main efforts will be on the following areas.

**UI**

You will need to obtain a new design suited for iPad depending on what you already have. If it is a simple interface, you port it to be viewed on iPad without a new design. But usually you need a iPad specific design.

You will have to change the layout of most screens to make it look good on the iPad. If auto layout is already used, it will be a little bit simpler. Otherwise I guess you will need to start thinking about separate storyboards and xibs for iPad specific screens.

**Code**

Assuming there is no additional functionality specific to the iPad, the main areas of change in code will be the those handling view presentation logic, navigation and animation. It all depends on the design you need to implement, but generally I would say you will need to change code that handles animation, presents new view controllers, handles storyboards etc.

**Resources**

You will need to provide resources specific to your iPad design.

**Testing**

Obviously you will need to do a LOT of testing :).

Eg: For example, location handling. There are no modern iPhones without GPS hardware, but iPads without cellular capabilities do not have GPS. So you location handling code might have to be rechecked. (It broke for me :))

**AppStore**

You will need to provide app store screenshots for the iPad screens.

Comment: Can the downvoter also please correct me where I went wrong?